# Scanner run until regex 0-255

Tags: java, regex

I am using Java.util.scanner to read a certain type of file.

When I get to a line containing a single integer between 1 and 255 I know that is the color depth of my file. However, my code below is not working. I assume i am doing something wrong with the regex so that it isn't detecting the integer.

```
        // while the next line is not the color depth
        // ^ = begining of a line, then anything of 0-255, $ = end of a line
        while (!scanner.hasNext("/^([0-255])$/")) {
            String nextLine = scanner.nextLine();
            // do something...
        }
        // gotten to the colordepth line
        int colorDepth = scanner.nextInt();
```

What do I need to change in order to loop through all the lines of the header until the color depth, and then read the color depth as an integer?

Edit: also tried `scanner.hasNext("^(1?[0-9]{1,2}|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])$")`

That also did not properly find the line with the color depth on it. I believe the issue lies in the end line characters. I have no trouble finding an integer but the issue is in headers that contain integers they are returned. The only unique identifying feature of the color depth is the fact that it is alone on this line.

Comment: *FYI:* `[0-255]` is the same as `[0125]` or `[5210]` or ..., which means it matches a single character (`0`, `1`, `2`, or `5`). It is certainly not a match for a numeric substring in the range "0" to "255". Try again.

Comment: `hasNext()` only looks at the next *token*, not the next *line*, so lines *not starting with* the numeric value will be skipped.

Comment: Java is not JavaScript, or any of the other languages using `/.../` to delimit regular expressions. `"/^([0-255])$/"` **cannot** match anything, because the regex is looking for tokens with a `/` character *before* the start of the token, and the `scanner` is likely separating tokens by whitespace, so that's an **impossibility**. Try again.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas ! I will have a look at that and see if I can fix it!!!